# enabling .vscode/tasks.json with gulefile.js tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i create dotnet x-platform [dnx] based asp.net 5 web apps, and apache cordova x-platform [acx] + angular2 based ionic2 mobile apps, they both setup a gulpfile.js containing a default set of gulp based task runner entries.

When i open those sources in vscode 1.0.0 and use f1 | tasks: configure task runner | gulp it generates a .vscode/task.json where "command": "gulp" is defined but it throws the warning dialog and output window errors shown below.

I have npm gulp@3.9.1 package installed locally.  Am i supposed to have some other package configuration in place to facilitate vscode task runner configuration that will use an existing gulpfile.js in my sources?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was I needed to have gulp installed as a global package in addition to the local package.json definition for it.

After doing a "npm install -g gulp" when I then executed f1 | tasks: configure task runner | gulp it setup a .vscode/tasks.json allowed me to use f1 | tasks: run tasks |  [ or ctrl+p |  ] to execute tasks defined and maintained in gulpfile.js .